# python customized map() function does not run

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do a mapping of string values to integer across various columns. I have written a customized code. However, when I call the code and pass my list, it doesnt do anything. Is there a syntax that I am missing?

```
def encode_cols(myList = [], *args):
    for col in myList:
        if col == 'Lot Shape':
            df[col] = df[col].map({'Reg':4, 'IR1':3, 'IR2':2, 'IR3':1})
        if col == 'Utilities':
            df[col] = df[col].map({'AllPub':4, 'NoSwer':3, 'NoSeWa':2, 'ELO':1})
        if col == 'Land Slope':
            df[col] = df[col].map({'Gtl':3, 'Mod':2,'Sev':1})

lst = ['Lot Shape','Utilities','Land Slope']
encode_cols(lst)
```

Comment: I think you forget `return df`

Comment: Ok, will try it now. I added return to each individual rows instead of adding them to the end.

Comment: @Zoozoo Your code raises `NameError` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns nothing and your list is not correctly defined.

A more Pandonic option is to use [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
def encode_cols(df, myList):
    for col in myList:
        if col == 'Lot Shape':
            df[col] = df[col].map({'Reg':4, 'IR1':3, 'IR2':2, 'IR3':1})
        if col == 'Utilities':
            df[col] = df[col].map({'AllPub':4, 'NoSwer':3, 'NoSeWa':2, 'ELO':1})
        if col == 'Land Slope':
            df[col] = df[col].map({'Gtl':3, 'Mod':2,'Sev':1})
    return df

lst = ['Lot Shape', 'Utilities', 'Land Slope']

df = df.pipe(encode_cols, lst)
```

Comment: I realized on my lst mistake and have them edited. I will try out as suggested. And thanks for introducing pipe to me. Didnt know it existed until now. I'm guessing I can read more on it on Python documentation?

Comment: Yep, added the link to my answer.